# Is there any global variable for PostgreSQL replication has configured or not

Tags: postgresql, master-slave-replication, uniqueidentifier

Is there any unique identifier or any global variable which can tell us if  replication is configured in current PostgreSQL server. Other than this query

```
select pg_is_in_recovery();
```

The above query results whether the server is in recovery or not, 
If 't' we consider it as a slave and we can judge it is a part of replication but

If it is 'f' how can we determine the corresponding PostgreSQL server is a part of replication.

Because even a server which is not a part of replication will also return 'f' as a result of the above query.

You can say, why can't I run a query like

```
select * from pg_stat_replication;
```

which will return the list of slaves connected to it. Then we can determine it is a master or not.

Am facing a scenario like "if the master is having only one slave, after some time that slave went down, then how can we determine replication is configured or not in that server"

Comment: What's wrong with `select * from pg_stat_replication;`? It will show one row for each stanby connected to the server where you run it.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name
 I think you didn't understand what am asking. I want to know how can I determine a server is a master server even though one and only slave having is went down. Because a standalone server will also return empty set on querying 
select * from pg_stat_replication;
like a master which lost its one and only slave server.
In a simple way, how can I differentiate a standalone server with master server?